# Do i need to install proprietary driver for AMD A8 APU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, amd-processor

I m using default driver for my AMD A8-5550M APU with Radeon HD Graphics(dual graphics).But i also found that proprietary driver is also available. Do i need to install it? Does installing it will make any difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any problems with the Xorg driver, and no program require the fglrx driver, I'd stick to the default one.

I've changed a lot between both drivers, so here are my experiences, also with an AMD A8 APU, but a different model:

- fglrx supports a more recent OpenGL version E.g. *Bioshock Infinite* requires fglrx, as the Mesa OpenGL version supported by the Xorg driver (in my case OpenGL 3.3) is too old to support the methods used by this game. And before anyone asks, yes, Bioshock Infinite has been ported to run natively on Linux. However, I've already played some games that would only work when not using fglrx.
- The Xorg driver seems to produce fewer glitches when rendering the desktop. E.g. the menu item selection in Cinnamon's launcher would start to jump around with fglrx if the mouse was between two entries and not hovering the text, whereas the problem doesn't occur with the Xorg driver.
- My boot animation was drawn in an incorrect screen ratio when using fglrx instead of the Xorg driver, although I mostly blame the unacceptably buggy UEFI implementation from HP.
- Programs using OpenCL (perform certain calculations on the GPU rather than the CPU) only work with fglrx, and not with the Xorg driver.
- I've heard and read rumors that the APU consumed less power when using fglrx, leading to a longer lasting on-battery-time, but I can't confirm this as I run my notebook on AC power 99% of time.

So it depends on what you need most: A driver of which you know it works (as you are currently using it) or one that supports newer technology, such as later OpenGL versions, e.g. required for some games. But as long as the Xorg driver works fine, you don't *need* fglrx.

If you decide to install the AMD proprietary fglrx driver, best fetch it directly from [AMD's website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-linux-beta-driver.aspx), as the versions in Ubuntu's repos are not quite up-to-date.